# Script to end/kill piled up Apps/Background processes in windows taskmanager of a exe

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

We have a java web application in which we are using a pdfconverter exe. Every 4-5 days, the exe getting piled up in the task manager. Atleast 100+ background process/apps of pdfconverter.exe gets piled up.
It stops the web application and pdf converter doesn't work. We have to manually end the process through taskmanager.
Can you please help me in letting me know if there's any script or automation can be written which monitors the number of processes and kills all the process once exceeded.
I want to know which tool can be used to create the script.

Comment: PowerShell: `get-process pdfconverter.exe | stop-process`

Comment: CMD: `taskkill /im pdfconverter.exe /f`

Comment: Please note: taskkill /im pdfconverter.exe /f using CMD Admin gives access denied error. But using taskmanager it can be killed using end task

Answer (score 2):

You could write a script in PowerShell to monitor how many processes there are and kill them if there are more than a certain number. E.g:

```
$PDFProcesses = Get-Process pdfconverter.exe

if ($PDFProcesses.count -gt 10) { 
    Try {
        $PDFProcesses | Stop-Process -ErrorAction Stop
    } Catch {
        Write-Warning "Stopping via PS failed. Trying Taskkill.."
        Taskkill.exe /im pdfconverter.exe /f
    }
}
```

You could then run this as a scheduled task to monitor for the issue at whatever interval you see fit.

Comment: Please note: taskkill /im pdfconverter.exe /f using CMD Admin gives access denied error. But using taskmanager it can be killed using end task.
will the script you have given work. Please help.

Comment: yes it usually does, but in this case it gives the error. Also, there are 100+ PIDs with same name pdfconverter.exe exe. Please let me know if there is any other way to kill them all.